# Angular set css dynamically of :before selector

Tags: css, angular

I need to label an upload button dynamically. My code so far:

```
<style>
   .file_upload_wrap.background_file:before {
    content: {{label}};  /* of course does not work */
  } 
</style>

<div class="file_upload_wrap background_file imgFormButton">
    <input type="file" class="file_upload" (change)="uploadFile($event, file)" name="file" id="file" [(ngModel)]="model.file"
      #file="ngModel">
</div>
```

How can I set the content dynamically?

Comment: Why are you writing js code in <style> tag?

Comment: this of course does not work. It should only illustrate what I want to do

Comment: a good question and I understand why u were just illustrating with this code, makes it clear what you are trying to do

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `attr` css function to retrieve the value of an attribute

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr

**component.css**

```
.file_upload_wrap.background_file:before {
    content: attr(data-content);  
}
```

**component.html**

```
<div class="file_upload_wrap background_file imgFormButton" [attr.data-content]="label">
    <input type="file" class="file_upload" (change)="uploadFile($event, file)" name="file" id="file" [(ngModel)]="model.file"
      #file="ngModel">
</div>
```

Edit: stackblitz showing example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-muysky?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Interesting method +1. I was just about to say you need to add it like `[attr.data-content]="{{label}}"`. But then you added the edit :P

Comment: @John Yeah I realised that while I was actually testing on stackblitz :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using css, and the :before selector, you could add an extra DOM-element before the div you want to decorate.

```
<label>{{label}}</label>
<div class="file_upload_wrap background_file imgFormButton">
        <input type="file" class="file_upload" (change)="uploadFile($event, file)" name="file" id="file" [(ngModel)]="model.file"
          #file="ngModel">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `@HostBinding` to defined CSS vars which you can then use in your .scss file, making it very easy to style `:before` and `:after` dynamically.

.ts:

```
size = 10
padding = 2

@HostBinding('attr.style')
public get cssVars() {
  return `
    --switch-size: ${this.size};
    --switch-padding: ${this.padding};
    --switch-size-inner: ${this.size - this.padding * 2};
  `;
}
```

.scss:

```
.my-class:before {
  height: calc(var(--switch-size) * 1px);
}
```

Comment: note - some people use DomSanitizer when using this approach but I didn't find it necessary (it worked without it) - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64252610/1205871