# Update the ::after pseudo class background color on the fly

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular Material Slide Toggle. I need to set the color of the handle and track to be the system color of our team, which is returned from the server. In this case, I cannot use static CSS to set the

```
.mdc-switch:enabled .mdc-switch__track::after {
  background-color: 'green' !important;
}

.mdc-switch.mdc-switch--selected:enabled .mdc-switch__handle::after {
  background-color: 'green' !important;
}
```

which is static and the css is built before the connection to server.

I saw some answers using @HostBinding:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64252610
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77201530/16833432

This may help but in my case it's not 100% match. The `.mdc-switch__track` and `.mdc-switch__handle` are deep DOM beneath MatSlideToggle, which means I cannot attach Directive to them, the direct parent DOM of the ::after. Besides, I don't quite understand the step between they run the getCssVars() and pass the value to CSS var.

Plus, Angular Material and its theming prefers static colors (correct me if I am wrong) and it does not match our needs. Wondering if there is another way to set it's theming color or the component colors on the fly?

Thanks!

Comment: I feel your best bet is "loading dinamicaly .css" like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73521654/how-to-dynamically-load-css-with-angular/73525150#73525150). I create a [new stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/4s6bym?file=src%2Fexample%2Fslide-toggle-overview-example.ts) with mat-slide-toggle for inspiration